# Can a wormhole change the wavelength of a light beam?

Tags: electromagnetism, time, wormholes

If a light beam went into one mouth of a wormhole, and came out the other, are their factors that would result in it coming out red or blue shifted?  Examples, if it came out of a mouth that was in the past (but possibly right next to where it went in, and in any event coming out before it went in) would it be blue or red shifted?  If the wormhole was accelerating toward the light beam when it went in would it affect the wavelength of the light when it came out?

Comment: Yes there are. For the classical Morris-Thorne wormhole it is even indicated in its name, the redshift function $\Phi$, as seen in $$ds^2 = - e^{2\Phi(t,l)} dt^2 + dl^2 + r^2(t,l) d\Omega^2$$